# SQL: How to select the highest priced used item for each day

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I need to produce a query that would give me the highest priced used product for each day where the total price of products sold that day exceeds 200.

```
SELECT *, max(price)
FROM products
WHERE products.`condition` = 'used' and products.price > 200
GROUP BY date_sold
```

Here is my products table http://prntscr.com/of3hjd

Comment: Have you tried any query by yourself?

Comment: @Tushar Yes, I've tried, but didn't get the expected result.

Comment: Can you post that query here?

Comment: don't post sample as  image .. post sample as  tabular text  ..

Comment: what is the expected result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a join with sum for price > 200  group by date_sol

```
    select  m.date_sold, max(m.price)
    from my_table m 
    inner join (
        select date_sold, sum(price)
        from my_table 
        group by date_sold
        having sum(price)>200 
    ) t on t.date_sold = m.date_sold 
    group by  m.date_sold
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions for this:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             sum(price) over (partition by date_sold) as sum_price,
             row_number() over (partition by date_sold, condition order by price desc) as seqnum
      from products p
     ) p
where sum_price > 200 and
      condition = 'used' and
      seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *, max(price) FROM products
where products.`condition` = 'used' and sum(products.price) > 200
GROUP BY day(date_sold)
```